# Homomorphic Function but not strong homomorphic

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, logic

Let's say we have the structure $(Z, Neigh, Even)$ where $Even(x)$ is true iff $x$ is even and $Neigh(x, y)$ is true iff $x = y + 1$ or $x = y − 1$. I wish to, if possible, construct a function $g$ from $Z$ to itself which is a homomorphism but NOT a strong homomorphism but I am not sure how that would work.

I am using the following definition: Assume that there are two structures A
and B with the same language, that is, using the same relations and functions. 
A mapping h from the domain A of A to the domain B of B is called a homomorphism
iff it satisfies the following conditions:

1. For every constant symbol $c, h(c^A) = c^B$;
2. For every n-ary function symbol f and all $a_1, . . . , a_n ∈ A,h(f^A(a_1, . . . , a_n) = f^B(h(a_1), . . . , h(a_n))$;
3. For every n-ary predicate symbol P and all $a_1, . . . , a_n ∈ A,
   P^A(a_1, . . . , a_n) ⇒ P^B(h(a_1), . . . , h(a_n))$.

A homomorphism h which satisfies in the third item for all predicates P and all
$a_1, . . . , a_n$ ∈ A the more restrictive condition
$P^A(a_1, . . . , a_n) ⇔ P^B(h(a_1), . . . , h(a_n))$
is called a strong homomorphism.

Comment: Define $f(2n)=0$ and $f(2n+1)=1$. Then, even numbers are sent to even numbers. If two numbers are neighbors then one is even and the other is odd. Therefore, they are sent, one to $0$ and the other to $1$. Therefore, neighbors are sent to neighbors. Hence, $f$ is homomorphism. It is not a strong homomorphism because, say $f(0)=0$ and $f(3)=1$  are neighbors, but $0$ and $3$ are not neighbors.

Comment: @YAlexandrov You should use answers for answers, not comments.

Comment: @DerekElkins Really? Oh my! That is news. Please, tell me more about what I should and what I shouldn't do.